# How to connect with PhpMyAdmin to the localhost via a Unix socket?

Tags: php, mysql

Can someone help with connecting to my web server?

In phpMyAdmin database is `Server: localhost:3306` when click on it I get:

```
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: MySQL
Server version: 5.5.52-cll - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

So how I can connect on it without an address or an IP?

The PhpMyAdmin and the MySQL run on the same, non-local system.

Comment: UNIX sockets are always local.

Comment: mostly it uses /var/run/mysql.sock if it's in same host, ip address is just attribute of php's mysql(i) driver, that is required and not used when .sock file is accessible.

Comment: ty for answer but i was have other problem.. localhost is just localhost... i put localhost and its working. incredibly... :D

Comment: I edited your question + clarified the last sentence. I think this is what you want to ask, but I am not sure. Feel free to rollback it, or explain me what you wanted to ask, if I wasn't enough experienced telepath. :-)

Comment: its ok. i was trying to connect to database. this is first time to see Server: localhost:3306. mostly've seen Server:"some link" for inserting to dbhost.  i did mistake in code and that was real problem. i did ask some friend for this localhost and no one knew but its solved now... localhost is just localhost... other link is no needed :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably You wanted this:

```
$socket = '/var/run/mysqld.sock'; // or: /tmp/mysqld.sock
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', "database", 3306, $socket);
// $db = mysql_connect('localhost:'.$socket, 'username', 'password');
```

Comment: ty for answer but i was have other problem.. localhost is just localhost... i put localhost and its working. incredibly... :D

Comment: @SandiBudic Then don't accept the answer, or ask a new question. I think you want to *configure* the phpmyadmin for unix socket connections. I did it already some years ago, it was not trivial but it is possible in its config file. Furthermore, if your English is not very good, is not a problem until it is understable, but following at least [these](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/advice-for-non-native-english-speakers/291370#291370) simple rules could improve it a lot.

Comment: i was tryng to connent to databe not to phpmyadmin. yeaaah i have little problem with english. im new here and how i can back old question? :)

Answer (score 0):

in config.inc.php, instead of

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
```

set

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '/tmp/mysql.sock';
```