# Docker: mariadb cant be accessed via phpmyadmin with 'localhost' as server

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mariadb, docker-container

This is my docker-compose.yml configuration:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: './apache/Dockerfile'
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '8100:80'
    env_file:
      - ./env/db.env
      - ./env/modx.env
    volumes:
      - './public_html:/var/www/html'
      - './elements:/var/www/html/elements'
  db:
    image: 'mariadb:10.3.38'
    networks:
      - my-mariadb-net
    volumes:
      - ./db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    env_file:
      - ./env/db.env
    ports:
      - '3307:3306'
    command: mysqld --sql-mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
    restart: always
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      PMA_PORT: 3306
      PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8110:80
```

On the production my connection via php to mysql server is as following:

```
$database_dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname;charset=utf8mb4';
```

Locally i have installed Docker on my linux and want to replicate this so i dont need to change it manually. The only way that i can connect to database server from my host machine is to put name of the service in there - in that case **db**. However, i would like to have it as on my producation which is **localhost**.

My question is: Is any good way to get it? Im not worried about security risks as it will be always locally.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is any good way to get it?

No.

Docker virtualizes network. There are 4 localhost here. Every containers has its own localhost interface. And your host has a localhost. They all are completely separate `lo` interfaces.

You can use `network: host` to *disable* network virtualization. Port redirection will also not affect anything, as there will be no network virtualization. This is *not* a good way, as it reduces the good things about docker and containerization, like separation.

A great solution, is to mount `/var/run/mysql` into the container and specify to straight use `mysql.sock`.

An acceptable solution is to make mysql listen on docker interface and use [host.docker.internal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach) to connect to host.

> Could you please share with me some more detailed information about mounting /var/run/mysql into the container and specify the straight use mysql.sock`?

You mount the mysql sock and connect to it

```
version: "3"
services:
  phpmyadmin:
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: /var/run/mysql/
        target: /var/run/mysql/
        read_only: true
```

in phpmyadmin configuration, from [How to connect with PhpMyAdmin to the localhost via a Unix socket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39937521/how-to-connect-with-phpmyadmin-to-the-localhost-via-a-unix-socket) :

```
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '/var/run/mysql/mysql.sock';
```

Comment: Hi Kamil,

Thank you for your reply. Could you please share with me some more detailed information about mounting `/var/run/mysql into the container and specify the straight use `mysql.sock`?

Also re: acceptable solution - by making MySQL listen on docker interface and use host.docker.internal to connect to host u mean adding:
extra_hosts:
    - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"

into docker compose?

Thank you so much!

Comment: `into docker compose?` yes